# Showing database files in new window with django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

Okay so, i am trying to show all the entries in my `FileField` Database and assign a html button to each entry. when the button is pressed, a new window will open and show the pdf file that is stored in the database.

**models.py**

```
class UploadedFile(models.Model):
the_file = models.FileField()

        def __str__(self):
    return self.the_file.name[:50]
```

**Views.py**

```
def show_file(response,pk):
    file_name=UploadedFile.objects.get(pk=pk)
    pdf = open( 'chartsapp/%s' % str(file_name), 'rb')
    response = FileResponse(pdf)
    return response

class Showing_File(ListView):
    model = UploadedFile
    template_name = 'index.html'
    context_object_name = 'the_uploaded_files_list'
```

**URLs.py**

```
path('show_file/<pk>', views.show_file),
```

**index.html**

```
{% for file in the_uploaded_files_list %}

    <p>  {{ file.the_file.name }} </p>
    <input type="button" value="Show Report" onclick="window.open('show_file/{{file.pk}}')">

{% endfor %}
```

**Settings.py**

```
MEDIA_URL = '/chartsapp/'
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "chartsapp")
```

What happens is my index.html loads, however i do not see the database entries names or corresponding buttons shown on the page.
I think maybe that the `Media_Url` and `Media_root` paths might be messing me up. I have read the documentation and played around with the paths but no joy.
please see picture below of the layout of the project, just incase it is the media roots that are messing it up.

Correct me if i am wrong but when i upload a to `FileField` in django admin. the file itself is not uploaded, the database is more of a path to the folder that it will be stored in. and that path should be the media root.

[image]

Comment: Does the database contain entries for UploadedFile model?

Comment: yes, i have uploaded a file called `faults.pd` to the database.